# Mesh cache modifier bake to keyframes

Tags: mesh, modifiers, keyframes, cache

I have such question. I made clothes & animated them in Marvelous designer, and then using Mesh cache modifier, opened this animation in Blender. And I would like to know, is it possible to turn the data from this modifier into keyframes?

Comment: Can you pls provide the .blend file?
There is a way but I need the .blend file to actually understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a softbody simulation and now you want to convert the simulation into keyframes.

If this fits then follow these steps

1.export your object as an alembic file

2.after the exportation is complete, open a new project and delete everything in the scene

3.Import the alembic file you just exported and hit play in the timeline. You will see the simulation running in your scene.

4.now select your object and add rigid body to it. Make the rigid body type "active" and animated(checkbox).

5.now with your object selected click on the object menu then rigid body and then click on "bake to keyframe". It might take some time depending on what you are baking

After the bake is complete you will have the cloth physics converted into keyframes. You can now also export it as a fbx file

Comment: No no, not softbody. I opened clothes animation from program "Marvelous designer" (file .pc2) with using modifier "Mesh cache". And I would like this animation to become keyframes, and not work from modifier.
I tried to do how you said, but after baking, only the first frame is displayed. I've tried "Bake to keyframe" & "Bake action" but no result.

Comment: can you provide the .blend file pls?I could do the work and record it and send it to you.

Comment: I seem to have found solution for this situation. If export to mdd, then mesh will turn into keyframes with shapre keys.
And thanks for taking the time & you trying to help.

Comment: Your welcome. Glad that you found the solution

Comment: @Juliya you mentioned you found solution. Can you explain how you obtained keyframes from cloth simulation file?

Comment: I exported mdd cache from Marvelous and in blender I added meshcache, but I still don't see keyframes